# error on 'then' callback after set data into firebase database using node.js

Tags: node.js, firebase-realtime-database, callback, promise

i have this code

```
app.get('/updateSaving/:name/:amount' , function(req,res){
   console.log('sending request update saving');
   var d = new Date();
   date = d.toString();
   firebase.database().ref('saving/'+ req.params.name).set({
     name : req.params.name,
     amount: req.params.amount,
     last_date : date
}).then(function(res){
    console.log('Saving Updated');
    res.json({ success: 'true' });
 });
})
```

After i called this code, the firebase had set the record but why i got error on my callback `res.json({ success: 'true' });`?
this is the error `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 4): TypeError: Cannot read property 'json' of undefined`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`Reference.set()` method returns a void promise](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.database.Reference#set). You declare `res` in your `then()` handler, which hides the `res` from `app.get()`.

The solution is to remove the `res` in your `set()` resolution handler:

```
app.get('/updateSaving/:name/:amount' , function(req,res){
   console.log('sending request update saving');
   var d = new Date();
   date = d.toString();
   firebase.database().ref('saving/'+ req.params.name).set({
     name : req.params.name,
     amount: req.params.amount,
     last_date : date
}).then(function(){
    console.log('Saving Updated');
    res.json({ success: 'true' });
 });
})
```